# Inserting/ Uploading Multiple Files to a specific row in a database table in PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, upload, insert

Problem: Only the last file upload inserted to the row (listing-amenities-safety-photos-id), which is supposed to be the entire photos selected during the upload.

HTML:

```
    <form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input name="upload[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="UPLOAD" />
    </form>
```

PHP:

```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    for ($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['upload']['name']); $i++) {
        $path = "../media/images/Listings/Set/";
        $ext = explode('.', basename( $_FILES['upload']['name'][$i]));
        $path = $path . md5(uniqid()) . "." . $ext[count($ext)-1]; 
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$i], $path);           

    }           

    $quotequery = "INSERT INTO `listing-details` (`listing-amenities-safety-photos-id`) VALUES ('$path')";
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $quotequery) == TRUE) {

        echo "File uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Upload failed.". mysqli_error($conn);
    }

}

?>
```

Photo to show only one entry is inserted:
[Image as proof that only one entry from $path is inserted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykiW3.png)

Note: All photos were uploaded successfully to the designated path. However, I can't get mysql to insert all the files in my row. I'm thinking like an array might solve my problem, but I'm not really an array expert, or even PHP! So please, any answer that is helpful but "marked as duplicate" or "down vote" will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Move your database query inside your of loop. `$path` gets overwritten on each pass, so as it stands, it will only insert the last one.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    for ($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['upload']['name']); $i++) {
        $path = "../media/images/Listings/Set/";
        $ext = explode('.', basename( $_FILES['upload']['name'][$i]));
        $path = $path . md5(uniqid()) . "." . $ext[count($ext)-1];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$i], $path);

        $quotequery = "INSERT INTO `listing-details` (`listing-amenities-safety-photos-id`) VALUES ('$path')";
        if (mysqli_query($conn, $quotequery) == TRUE) {

            echo "File uploaded.";
        } else {
            echo "Upload failed.". mysqli_error($conn);
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to disclose this: I tried putting the query inside the loop, and same thing happened: only most recent entry.

Comment: Echo out your query when you insert it. Inside of the loop, the path should be different each time.

Comment: please enlighten me, how to i make the path different?

Comment: It looks like you should be creating a new path each time. If you're not, take a look at why. It could be the uniqid, or the md5 hashing.

Comment: wait, on hindsight, it did work, it just created more rows because I did not indicated a WHERE "clause" to really specify one and only one row. I tried using the WHERE clause, setting a specific "id" from the row to where the files should be inserted. But, instead, it gives me this: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE ...

Comment: INSERT does not have a WHERE clause. You can check to see if the ID exists first, then do an INSERT or UPDATE as needed.